# Proper font install? Conflict with new installed font in some cases. Can't use downloaded fonts

Tags: bash, xubuntu, fonts, xfce

Recently I downloaded the .oft [files](https://fontawesome.com/download) from [fontawesome](https://fontawesome.com/), so I could print more interesting stuff inside the terminal. I started by putting them inside ~/local/share/fonts folder and restarting the cache.

However, certain characters aren't being displayed properly, but being replaced by some  weird character:
[first mark should be "volume off" symbol and last should be "volume down"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HJjz.png)

I couldn't find any solution that didn't resemble replacing the default font systemwide. I suspect that ubuntu has some pack with a higher priority compared to custom ones, but I'm not sure.

If there is a way to specify which font to use for a specific program or vice versa, [similar to changing colors](https://www.theurbanpenguin.com/4184-2/), then that would be a perfect. I used a bash script in the screenshot above, but I could use any utility.

If there is a way to discover and replace which font is actually conflicting with the custom one, that would be perfect as well

Comment: @Nmath Actually, I should  edit that. I'm indeed writing a program, but that screenshot is from a simple bash script with a bunch of "printf"s. Also, I'm not using gnome

Comment: @Nmath I have an xubuntu and xfce tag for this, but if you insist I will specify that in future questions. Now... the problem probably lies between ubuntu config and the program, so much so that my question on stack got closed. However, if the solution could come from the program than that would be enough, any executable that can produce the right output is enough. Anyway, that won't be necessary since I just fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that reloading the cache with `fc-cache -f -v` wasn't enough.

However, after restarting my computer everthing worked perfectly. There is no more conflict